# Read key from powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I created C# app which adds new cmdlets to powershell. 
Now I open the powershell and during the execution of the cmdlet, if a user types "ctrl+c", I want to stop the execution and terminate.

How can I read key from powershell in my c# application?
I'm looking for something like Console.Readkey()

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect Ctrl-C from a C# app you can use the [Console.CancelKeyPress event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        };

    while (true)
    {
        // Do Stuff.
    }
}
```

However, I may not understand your question, as a normal C# app already dies with Ctrl-C by default.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. For clarification, these are the steps I've done.
[1] I created a new cmdlet using c# 
[2] open powershell and run the cmdlet 
[3] get cancel event from user and stop the execution.//
Is powershell also a console application?
I'm surprsied Console event handler catches the event from powershell. I thought I'd need to use powershell specific .net method like ReadHostCommand or etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Console.CancelKyePress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx) event.